Arriving the day before my UK visa starts
I have a working visa with the start date of the 31st of August for the UK. However my flight departs and arrives on the 30th of August in the UK. Will that be a problem?

What kind of work visa do you have exactly, and what is your citizenship?

Is there a reason why you think it might not be a problem?

Yes, it’s a problem. While UK border control might well be willing to let you in a day early, you won’t get that far; the airline will not let you board without a valid visa, and your visa will not (yet) be valid. Change your flight.
This assumes, BTW, that you actually need a visa to enter the UK. If that’s not the case, other options may be available.

If OP does not need a visa to travel to the UK (as a visitor), it seems there’s still a requirement to exit and then re-enter the UK after the visa starts. It may depend on the exact type of visa though.
